# YouTube acting strangely

Tags: firefox, youtube

For the last couple of months, I can be browsing the YouTube web site, **not** watching a video, and all of a sudden, audio from a advertisement will start playing.  Sometimes, this audio will start playing along with a video I'm watching.  If I close out that tab in Firefox, it stops.  I've had this happen even while I'm doing something completely different on the machine and YouTube has been setting idle for long periods of time.

I have all the pop-ups blocked, etc.

Anybody else experiencing this?  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it always the same audio?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It's the "Easy Youtube Video Downloader".  Apparently they now had advertising tied to it.  Once I disabled this extension, the problem went away.